# How to group/club elements in a 2D list based on the 1D elements belonging to another 2D list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I'm new to Python and I have a question on involving data structures and algorithms(which are essential skills that a  programmer should have)

There are two lists L1 AND L2.

```
L1= [[0.0, 0.22],[0.0, 0.13],[0.03, 0.19],[0.14, 0.49],[0.2, 0.55], 
     [0.5,0.61],[0.56, 0.72],[0.62, 0.82],[0.0, 0.11], [0.03, 0.31],
     [0.12, 0.47], [0.32, 0.55], [0.48, 0.72], [0.56, 0.75],[0.0, 0.09], 
     [0.03, 0.16]]
L2= [['eɪ'], ['æ', 'f', 'ɹ', 'i', 'k', 'ʌ', 'n'],['eɪ', 'ʤ', 'ʌ', 'n', 
     't', 's'], ['ɔ', 'l']]
  #I want the final output like this as a 3D array
   [[['eɪ',0.0, 0.22]],[['æ',0.0, 0.13],['f',0.03, 0.19],['ɹ',0.14, 0.49],['i', 0.2, 0.55], 
     ['k',0.5,0.61],['ʌ',0.56, 0.72],['n',0.62, 0.82]],[['eɪ',0.0, 0.11], ['ʤ',0.03, 0.31],
     ['ʌ',0.12, 0.47], ['n',0.32, 0.55], ['t',0.48, 0.72], ['s',0.56, 0.75]],[['ɔ',0.0, 0.09], 
     ['l',0.03, 0.16]]]
```

Comment: Can you please give more details as to what your problem is and how you got to the expected output?

Comment: @Karl So basically,the elements in L1 has to be mapped with the elements in L2 . Another hint would be to look for 0.0 in L1. The iteration starts from the part where it begins with 0.0 and should stop just before the next element also starts with 0.0.

Comment: @Karl Um,I think I've mentioned how I want the final output to be like. I'm not quite sure why you didn't understand the problem sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need this:

```
L1_it = iter(L1)

result = [[[L2_element, *next(L1_it)] for L2_element in sublist] for sublist in L2]
```

This can be expanded as follows:

```
L1_it = iter(L1)

result = []

for L2_sublist in L2:
    result_sublist = []
    for L2_element in L2_sublist:
        result_sublist.append([L2_element, *next(L1_it)])

    result.append(result_sublist)
```

Both methods give the same result:

```
[[['eɪ', 0.0, 0.22]], [['æ', 0.0, 0.13], ['f', 0.03, 0.19], ['ɹ', 0.14, 0.49], ['i', 0.2, 0.55], ['k', 0.5, 0.61], ['ʌ', 0.56, 0.72], ['n', 0.62, 0.82]], [['eɪ', 0.0, 0.11], ['ʤ', 0.03, 0.31], ['ʌ', 0.12, 0.47], ['n', 0.32, 0.55], ['t', 0.48, 0.72], ['s', 0.56, 0.75]], [['ɔ', 0.0, 0.09], ['l', 0.03, 0.16]]]
```

To get to this piece of code, we observe that the expected result is of the same structure as `L2`, except that the elements in running order from `L1` are appended to each sublist in `L2` as if it were flattened.

Comment: I tried both the code snippets that you posted. But it gives an error at line 
--------------- > StopIteration: result_sublist.append([L2_element, *next(L1_it)]).

Comment: @enviz Did you run both of them from the start? Every time you run the `list` comprehension/for loop, you *must* rerun `L1_it = iter(L1)`.

Comment: By the way,I forgot to mention that the actual lengths of L1 and L2 in my program are much larger than what's used in the question. Does your solution depend on the lengths of L1 and L2?

Comment: Not necessarily. However, it assumes that the number of elements in `L1` is the same as the number of elements in `L2`, if flattened. The error you are getting suggests that this is not the case - in particular, that `L1` is shorter than expected.

Comment: yes sir,it worked after L1_it = iter(L1) was added below result.append(result_sublist) within the for loop. Could you please update your solution with the changes?  Thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: @enviz while that would make your code run, I don't think it's actually what you're looking for. Try it on the data you provided in the question and you will see that it returns something different from what you expected. You might need to edit the question to provide data that more accurately represents your actual dataset.

Comment: And also,should the question be slightly modified in anyway so that other coders can find it easily if they're looking for a similar solution?

Comment: It's true that the solution you gave works for the data provided in the question. But when the lengths are huge(in the actual problem) , it fails and gives an error. Now that I realize that the lengths of L1 and L2 did kinda matter in this case.